# Confused about python, lists/generator objects

Tags: python

Not sure if this has been asked before but I couldn't find a proper, clear explanation.

I had a concern about something related to python syntax.

While practicing some python, I Intuitively assumed this would print all the elements of the list; list1.

But it doesn't seem to do so, why would that be?

I could obviously print it in many other ways; but I fail to understand the inherent python logic at play here.

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]

print(list1[i] for i in range(len(list1)))
```

I expected the output to be '[1, 2, 3, 4]', but it instead prints a generator object.

Comment: A generator object is not automatically converted to a tuple, list or anything. `print` shows what it gets.

Comment: Even if you did manage to do this, it would still print it literally: `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. You need to do `[print(list1[i]) for i in range(len(list1)))]`

Answer (score 4):

You need to surround `list1[i] for i in range(len(list))` with `[]` to indicate that it's a list. Although `list1` is a list, you are trying to use a generator expression to print it out, which will return a generator object (type of iterable similar to a list.) Without specifying you want to convert the generator to a list, it won't print a list. (A generator expression converted to a list is called list comprehension.)

Even if you did do this, it would still print it `[1, 2, 3, 4]` rather than `1 2 3 4`. You need to do `[print(list1[i], end=" ") for i in range(len(list1)))]` for that to work. There are far better ways of doing this: see donkopotamus's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `(list1[i] for i in range(len(list)))` defines a generator object.  So that is what is printed.

If you wish to print a list, then make it a *list comprehension* rather than a generator, and print that:

```
print( [list1[i] for i in range(len(list1))] )
```

Alternatively, you could force evaluation of the generator into a `tuple` (or `list` or `set`), by passing the generator to the appropriate type using eg

```
print(tuple(list1[i] for i in range(len(list1))))
```

In order to get the specific output you intended (space separated) of `1 2 3 4` you could use `str.join` in the following way:

```
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print(" ".join(list1[i] for i in range(len(list1))))
1 2 3 4
```

or unpack the list into `print` (this will not work in python 2, as in python 2 `print` is not a function)

```
>>> print(*(list1[i] for i in range(len(list1))))
1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(list1[i] for i in range(len(list1)))
```

is indeed a generator object, equivalent to simply

```
(x for x in list1)
```

You're passing that generator to `print` as a single argument, so `print` simply prints it: it does not extract the elements from it.

Alternatively, you can unpack it as you pass it to `print`:

```
print(*(list1[i] for i in range(len(list1))))
```

This will pass each element of the generated sequence to `print` as a separate argument, so they should each get printed.

If you simply meant to print your list, any of the following would have worked:

```
print(list1) 
print([list1[i] for i in range(len(list1))])
print([x for x in list1])
```

The use of square brackets makes a list comprehension rather than a generator expression.

Answer (score 0):

There is something called list comprehension and generator expression in python. They are awesome tools, you can find more info by googling. [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comprehensions-in-python/) is a link.

Basically, you can make a list on the fly in python.

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
squared_list = [i*i for i in list1]
```

would return a list with all the items squared. However, is we say

```
squared_gen_list = (i*i for i in list1)
```

this returns what is known as a generator object. That is what is happening in your case, as you can see from the syntax and so you are just printing that out. Hope that clears up the confusion.